# Cmidrule align same line using arraystretch

Tags: tables, booktabs

Consecutive cmidrule need to align same line(as given in the second part of table)
even using arraystretch? [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% Correct for \cmidrule colour adjustment/vertical skip
\newcommand{\corcmidrule}[1][2pt]{% \corcmidrule[<len>]
  \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip-\belowrulesep-\aboverulesep-#1\relax]%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 \\
  \cmidrule[2pt](lr){1-1}\corcmidrule\arrayrulecolor{blue}%
  \cmidrule[2pt](lr){2-2}\corcmidrule\arrayrulecolor{black}%
  \cmidrule[2pt](lr){3-3}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 \\
  \cmidrule[5pt](lr){1-1}\corcmidrule[5pt]\arrayrulecolor{blue}%
  \cmidrule[3pt](lr){2-2}\corcmidrule[3pt]\arrayrulecolor{orange}%
  \cmidrule[7pt](lr){3-3}\arrayrulecolor{black}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip\def\arraystretch{1.4}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 \\
  \cmidrule[5pt](lr){1-1}\corcmidrule[5pt]\arrayrulecolor{blue}%
  \cmidrule[3pt](lr){2-2}\corcmidrule[3pt]\arrayrulecolor{orange}%
  \cmidrule[7pt](lr){3-3}\arrayrulecolor{black}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add *minimal* code that produces that output?

Comment: Please, edit your question and add above code there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking into account the value of `\arraystretch` in the definition of `\corcmidrule`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% Correct for \cmidrule colour adjustment/vertical skip
\newcommand{\corcmidrule}[1][2pt]{% \corcmidrule[<len>]
  \\[\dimexpr-\arraystretch\normalbaselineskip-\belowrulesep-\aboverulesep-#1\relax]%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 \\
  \cmidrule[2pt](lr){1-1}\corcmidrule\arrayrulecolor{blue}%
  \cmidrule[2pt](lr){2-2}\corcmidrule\arrayrulecolor{black}%
  \cmidrule[2pt](lr){3-3}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 \\
  \cmidrule[5pt](lr){1-1}\corcmidrule[5pt]\arrayrulecolor{blue}%
  \cmidrule[3pt](lr){2-2}\corcmidrule[3pt]\arrayrulecolor{orange}%
  \cmidrule[7pt](lr){3-3}\arrayrulecolor{black}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip\def\arraystretch{1.4}


\begin{tabular}{lll}
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 \\
  \cmidrule[5pt](lr){1-1}\corcmidrule[5pt]\arrayrulecolor{blue}%
  \cmidrule[3pt](lr){2-2}\corcmidrule[3pt]\arrayrulecolor{orange}%
  \cmidrule[7pt](lr){3-3}\arrayrulecolor{black}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I spent an hour, you gave solution minutes, Thank you Leandriis.